# Unity Android Game Redirecting to setting/wifi screen automatically

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am working on mobile game project Android and IOS.

I used 3 plugins in my game (OneSignal, Google Play Game Services and OpenIAB).

I make the build in my android device (LG Nexus 5x) and everything is working fine, I tested on some Hawaii devices and its pretty good.

But when I tried this on Samsung S4 weird thing started happening, when I play game with my wifi on everything run smoothly, but when i turned off the wifi game automatically redirect me to the settings screen of android device.

I was searching the issue when the other colleague came to me with another Samsung S4 device in which if wifi is off the game redirect user to the wifi enabling screen in settings BUT if you leave the wifi off and came back to game it automatically turn on the wifi and connect to it.

I was searching alot with issues in plugins and in my game but everything is fine and didn't fine any other related issue.

Please Help to cure this weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes occurs when at the time of building the game, you must have set the base version in which the game runs as something which is more advanced than  the s4 mobile. Also there is an alternative option wich can llow you to play the game without net connection. you may check out that and rebuild it. hope this works!